# Use returned JSON from database in HTML with Play framework

Tags: javascript, java, html, json, playframework

I'm trying to get a login to work on my project, but I can't find any info on how to display the JSON string returned to the webpage.

My code:

Security.java:

```
public Person webLogin(Person p){
    Query q = JPA.em().createQuery("select p from Person p");
    List<Person> results = q.getResultList();
    if(!results.isEmpty()){
        for(Person person : results){
            if(person.email.equals(p.email) && person.password.equals(p.password)){
                return person;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Application.java:

```
public Result webLogin() {
    Person person = Form.form(Person.class).bindFromRequest().get();
    Person authenticatedPerson = security.webLogin(person);

    if(authenticatedPerson != null){
            return ok(toJson(authenticatedPerson));
    }
    return ok();
}
```

Routes.conf:

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
POST    /login                      controllers.Application.login()
POST    /weblogin                   controllers.Application.webLogin()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

I do get a result:

```
{"id":3,"email":"test@test.com","password":"test123"}
```

Which appears on a blank html page on "localhost:9000/weblogin".

For future work, when I add "Firstname" or "Username" to the login details, how do I display them at the top of the webpage, and have other HTML code at the rest of the page?

Similar to e.g Facebook, where at the top right your name is displayed, then at the rest of the page you can navigate through facebook.

Do I have to use Javascript? In that case, how do I get js to find the returned JSON string?

Comment: Do some reading up on how AJAX works using javascript

Answer (score 0):

You have to do an AJAX query, in javascript. This has nothing to do with Play.
Example with jquery:

```
$.getJSON("/weblogin",function(data){
  $("#email").text(data.email)
}
```